# Getting users from auth table in Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase auth and I do not have firebase DB enabled. In my react-admin dashboard, I want to output all of the users that are in the users section in the Authentication tab from the firebase console. [image: users tab in authentication]

Is there any way to access these users?

Comment: There is no client-side API to get a list of users from Firebase Authentication, as that would be a security risk (since anyone can call that API with your configuration data. The common workarounds are to either store the user data in Firestore or Realtime Database and secure it through security rules, or to look it up server-side using the Admin SDK and expose that in a custom API you secure yourself. Both have been covered quite a few times before, so I'll link some of those answers rather than repeating them.'